# Why does insertInto fail when working with tables in non-default database?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.4

I'm using Spark 1.4.0 (PySpark). I have a DataFrame loaded from Hive table using this query:

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
table1_contents = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM my_db.table1")
```

When I attempt to insert data from `table1_contents` after some transformations, into table2 using DataFrameWriter#insertInto function:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(transformed_data_from_table1).write.insertInto('my_db.table2')
```

I encounter this error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o364.insertInto.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: no such table my_db.table2;
```

I know my table is existing because when I type:

```
print sqlContext.tableNames('my_db')
```

table1 and table2 are displayed. Can anyone help about this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue. It looks like the insertInto function might have some bug when writing to non-default database. After I change the target table to default database, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [reported bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11683). Apparently, the issue is resolved only in the upcoming version 1.6.0.

As a workaround you can do what you said, or go with the default database as mentioned by @guoxian. You could also try out the version 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.

EDIT: The JIRA issue I linked is for Spark Scala version, so I can't say if this issue is fixed in PySpark v 1.6.0. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Hi，I don't know if you had solved the problem. In my work I got the similar issue and I solved  it. My spark version is 1.40, and so I think there is no bug in the program @Ton Torres. The problem is you used the sqlContext instead of hiveContext. When you need to operate hive you had better use hiveContext to  create DataFrame like this

```
    val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
    dfresult = hiveContext.createDataFrame(temp,structType)
    hiveContext.sql("use default")
    dtResult.write.insertInto("tablename")
```

May you good luck

Comment: My sqlContext is a HiveContext. See the first line of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make

`sqlContext.createDataFrame(transformed_data_from_table1).write.insertInto('my_db.table2')`

working, however, it seems SparkSQL supports `INSERT` statements as string.

`sqlContext.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE my_db.table2...");`

and this one works.

Although I still look forward to the time that my original question will be answered and working (hopefully on future version of Spark, if this is a bug).